# Modelagem de Banco de Dados, relação muitos para muitos entre duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 3 websites que irão compartilhar o mesmo banco de dados.
São 3 tabelas: Noticias, Galeria de Fotos, Blog.
Será apenas um sistema de gerenciamento para os 3 websites.

Exemplo: o usuário irá salvar uma notícia que pertencera apenas para 2 websites.

Questão: Qual a melhor forma de modelar o banco de dados?

Criar uma tabela e gravar por exemplo o código do site e da notícia para ser recuperada nos sites que podem exibi-las?
Criar apenas um campo em cada tabela e salvar quais sites essa a notícia pertence? Pensei de ser dessa forma, mas como gravar esses dados que depois possa fazer a busca com SQL de forma eficiente?

Comment: Pergunta baseada em opiniões não fazem parte do escopo do site. Você pode reformular a sua pergunta, por gentileza? Pois se não as respostas serão baseadas em opiniões, e cada um responderá "Eu acho isso ou aquilo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria assim, visto que a mesma noticia pode ser exibida em 2 ou mais sites:

Crie uma tabela `Sites` com as colunas `id` (1, 2 e 3) e coluna `url` (endereço do website, ex: www.meusite.com), aí você insere logo os sites.

Depois criava uma tabela pivot `Sites_Noticias` visto que a relação é N:N (muitas noticias para muitos websites), esta é a tabela que vai relacionar os `Sites` com as `Noticias`. Nesta tabela armazenava somente dois dados, criava uma coluna `id_noticia` e `id_site`

Assim desta maneira você já tem a noticia/noticias e o site/sites relecionados.

Agora por ex:

Tabela `Sites`:

**id | url**

1 | www.meusite1.com

2 | www.meusite2.com

3 | www.meusite3.com

Tabela `Sites_Noticias`:

**id_site | id_noticia**

1 | 3

2 | 1

1 | 2

3 | 1

Neste exemplo podemos ver que a noticia cujo id é 1 vai aparecer no site cujo id é 2 (www.meusite2.com) e no site cujo id é 3 (www.meusite3.com). No site 1 (www.meusite1.com) vão ser publicadas as noticias com os id's 3 e 2.

Pela tabela pivot (`Sites_Noticias`), consoante o site onde estiver, pode ir buscar as noticias (à tabela `Noticias`) que devem ser mostradas. Neste exemplo se tivermos no site 1 vamos buscar as noticias cujos id's são id's 3 e 2.

`SQL` para ir buscar as noticias que fazem parte do site `www.meusite1.com`:

```
SELECT Noticias.* FROM Sites JOIN Sites_Noticias ON Sites.id = Sites_Noticias.id_site JOIN Noticias ON Noticias.id = Sites_Noticias.id_noticia WHERE Sites.url="www.meusite1.com";
```

Peço desculpa pela má formatação da resposta, tentei ser o mais claro possível.